# Openlayers draw not scaling correctly to map size

Tags: ionic-framework, openlayers, openlayers-3

I currently have an openlayers map that I am putting a draw overlay on top of. The problem is that when I scale the div container holding the map it doesn't actually scale the drawing layer correctly, so the pointer does not align with the mouse location. If I don't do any scaling it lines up correctly. I have also tried setting the html and body to 100% width in addition to the div tag, but that has not worked either.

[mouse aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5A5h.png)

[mouse not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Squ9.png)

here is my map typesscript code:

```
// create the bing maps layer
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
    key: 'AioGchlm6KiMF-8ws9hq9PEJKSZzGXj8aZ1OrDt-MlN_NY907-YdiaraNT9sCodZ',
    imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels',
    maxZoom: 19
  })
});

// generate the actual map
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 10
  })
});

// holds each of the drawings
var features = new ol.Collection();

// allows the user to draw a polygon on the map
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  features: features,
  type: 'Polygon'
});
map.addInteraction(draw);

// adds the polygon to the features collection when the drawing is complete
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features}),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#ffcc33',
      width: 2
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 4,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33'
      })
    })
  })
});
featureOverlay.setMap(map);

// allows the user to modify the drawings
var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  features: features,
/*
  deleteCondition: function(event) {
    return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
        ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
  }
*/
});
map.addInteraction(modify);
```

and the html code:

```
<div #map id="map"></div>
```

and the css:

```
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

it is also probably worth noting that I am doing this inside an ionic 3 project.

Comment: You need to call `map.updateSize()` each time you resize your div

Comment: where should i call this at? I put the function in a button and when i click it it works correctly, but if I put it in my function that creates the map it doesn't work

Comment: doesnt work????????